# SSRS Integration with Azure DevOps

Tags: sql-server, azure, reporting-services, azure-devops

I'm attempting to find a good read on how to connect our Azure DevOps reporting data that drives the reports within DevOps to our internal SSRS. Having not done this before, I'm curious if this is even possible or if I can just obtain a connection string/WebApi somewhere with a list of tables/JSON. The current reports offered by DevOps are not extensive enough for our need and we need to expand upon them and would prefer to do this in house.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The SQL Server reporting solution is based on a data warehouse and OLAP cube coupled with a SQL Server Reporting server to host reports.

> Currently ,integration with the data warehouse and SQL Server
>   Reporting Services is only supported for on-premises **Azure DevOps**
>   **Server 2019** and **Team Foundation Server** (TFS). If you don't have a
>   reporting site and want to add it, see [Add reports to a project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/admin/add-reports-to-a-team-project?view=azure-devops-2019).

For information on what is supported for Azure DevOps Services, see [Dashboards and reports overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/dashboards/overview?view=azure-devops).

This is stated in this official [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/sql-reports/reporting-services-reports?view=azure-devops-2019&viewFallbackFrom=azure-devops), for details,please refer to it.

If you want to integrate SSRS with Azure DevOsp Service , it is currently unachievable . You could add your request for this feature on our [UserVoice](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21) site , which is our main forum for product suggestions. In addition, you could also vote that suggestion ticket and share your comment there, so product team would provide the updates if they view it.